# Average Calculator Program Using Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageMark{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int mark[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            System.out.printf("Enter integer mark %s between 0 and 100: ", i + 1);

        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for entering your marks.\n");
        double average = (mark[0] + mark[1] + mark[2] + mark[3]) * 0.25;
        String grade;
        if (average >= 90) {
            grade = "A+";
        } else if (average >= 80) {
            grade = "A";
        } else if (average >= 70) {
            grade = "B";
        } else if (average >= 60) {
            grade = "C";
        } else if (average >= 50) {
            grade = "D";
        } else
            grade = "F";
        System.out.printf("Your average is: %.2f\n", average);
        System.out.printf("Your average of %.2f has a letter grade of %s", average, grade);
    }

}
```

//Hi sorry about the prior edit, I am new to this site. This is the code I wrote but I'm not sure why it won't run. It seems something might be missing but I'm 
quite unclear. Please help thank you

Comment: Your question is quite broad and could be interpreted by some as a request for others to do your homework for you, or at least to start it for you. I know that this is not what you intended, but to improve your question greatly and to help you get quick high quality answers, please show the code you've written, tell the problems you're having with it, and use this to ask a much more specific and answerable question. Please have a look at the [help] and the [ask] for more on site best practices when asking a question.

Comment: You write method that accepts 4 values, add them and divide by 4. Use double

Comment: @GhostCat: we have to assume good intentions -- per the new policies. So I am

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry about that, and thank you for providing me new resources. I greatly appreicate it!

Comment: OK great, you've posted your code. Now to make the question complete, again post the requirements (which you've deleted), the problems that you're having with this code, and your question(s). Something more than "I don't know what is wrong with it" -- tell us what's wrong. Does it compile? Does it run? Does it misbehave, and if so, how?

Comment: At the first glance, you've never read and assign (in your array) the inputs

Comment: Removed my down-vote since you posted the code.

Comment: Hello, i'm back and my program seems to misbehave. it is in an infinite loop and will not stop displaying "Enter mark 1 between 0 and 100: " on the console

Comment: When updating your code please add updates and not change the initial code.  Some comments are based on your original post and changing that will make the comments unclear and not useful.   Also, you should post the actual issue (like the compiler error messages) so people can better understand the issue.  Also, what version of Java are you using would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost there, just missing to store the values entered by user :

1. Store the marks in the array :

   ```
   System.out.println("Enter the marks : ");   
   for (int i =0; i < mark.length; i ++) {     
       System.out.printf("Enter integer mark %s between 0 and 100: ", i + 1);
       // assign each input to an index of the array
       mark[i] = input.nextInt();
   }
   ```

I would also advice you to declare the array like below   rather than just initialing all the indexes to 0

```
int mark[] = new int[4];
```

The rest of your code works as it is.

Answer (score 1):

In below program , I am giving flexibility to user to enter number of subjects. Scanner allows the user to read values of various types. System.in: An InputStream which is typically connected to keyboard input of console program.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

class AverageMarks
{
   public static void main(String args[])
  {

    int i;

    System.out.println("Enter number of subjects");

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 //Here we are taking number of subjects from user
    int n=sc.nextInt();


    //Set array to no of subject
    int[] a=new int[n];

    double avg=0;


    System.out.println("Enter marks");
    //  Taking marks from user for n no of subjects
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
 // Calculating total marks of subjects in avg variable
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      avg=avg+a[i];
      System.out.println("Total marks of subjects : => "+avg);
    }

    //Calculating average % using total/no of subject formula

    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
      System.out.print(a[i]+",");
    }
    System.out.println(a[i]+") ="+avg/n);
  }
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: added comments for better understanding , Can you please vote for my answer ?. Thanks for your guidance. I will take care next time

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the code.

The first error you see is:

> AverageMark.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
>           System.out.println("Thanks for entering your marks.\n");

This is because you have a closing curly brace where it is not needed.  The Java compiler is having difficulty interpreting the structure of your program.  Remove line 11.  You need to have matching curly braces to form a syntactically correct program.  Did you mean to include a for loop ?

Once you correct that and recompile you'll find that:

> AverageMark.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
>           System.out.printf("Enter integer mark %s between 0 and 100: ", i + 1);
>     symbol:   variable i   location: class AverageMark 1 error

Add the definition for `int i=0` before the reference to `i` on line 10.

It should then compile and you can start debugging.